How does one do this translation?

Good day! I am having a bit of trouble understanding the part where the paper said "Then a simple translation in $x$ can absorb the linear term $\langle b,x \rangle$ into the quadratic form." Am I correct in under standing that $f$, after translation, would become something like $f(x) = (x-x_0)^TA(x-x_0)$? I tried doing this translation for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ where $x = [x_1 \hspace{4pt} x_2]^T$, $b = [b_1 \hspace{4pt} b_2]^T$, $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4 \end{bmatrix}$. I expanded this and it turned out pretty gnarly in the middle and I cannot do completion of squares anymore. Is there an easier way to do this? Thank you!

I feel like there's more to it than that, though. There's a lot of extra terms when you expand the expression; I don't think that will just take care of it. Although I'll look into this further. Thanks.

I disagree with NicNic8, the replacement only provides the change to eigenbasis. I think you, @ameagari, are on the right track to cancel out the linear term. Is it obligatory to make the constant term vanish as well? How does it affect the initial problem, what is $f$ anyway?

I have found the original paper you've taken the screenshot from and here's the deal. Your approach is absolutely correct, you shouldn't be confused with the constant terms because later on they are cancelled with the derivative operator. I'll sketch out the solution, see if it helps.
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \langle x, Ax\rangle \, + \langle b, x\rangle. 
$$
Consider the variable change: $y=x-a$
$$
f(y) = \frac{1}{2} \langle y+a, A(y+a)\rangle \, + \langle b, y+a\rangle = 
\frac{1}{2} \langle y, Ay\rangle \, + \frac{1}{2} \langle a, (A+A^*)y\rangle \, + \langle b, y\rangle + \langle b, a\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \langle a, Aa\rangle
$$
Forgetting about the constant terms, all we have to consider is the second and third term. Equation their sum to zero yields:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \langle a, (A+A^*)y\rangle \, + \langle b, y\rangle = 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \\
 \langle \frac{1}{2}(A+A^*) a, y\rangle \, + \langle b, y\rangle = \langle \frac{1}{2}(A+A^*) a + b, y\rangle = 0 
$$
for all $y$. Hence: $(A+A^*) a + 2b = 0 \Leftrightarrow a = -2(A+A^*)^{-1}b$.
That's it.

I think I need more time trying to absorb this but this answer assured me that I'm on the right track! Thank you!
